# How can I capture the same keyboard event from different threads using crossterm in rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, keyboard-events, crossterm

I have a loop which spawns a set of threads. Each thread is listening to a different key. I want to do something in each thread based on the character pressed event.

This is the function I am using. (`InputConfig` is just a struct that contains the key, for example   and `x`):

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
pub fn wait_until_user_input(input_config: &InputConfig) {
    loop {
        if let Ok(_) = poll(Duration::from_millis(20)) {
            println!("Event polled, expecting '{}'", input_config.key.unwrap());
            match read().unwrap() {
                Event::Key(KeyEvent {
                    code,
                    modifiers: _,
                    kind,
                    state: _,
                }) => {
                    if code == KeyCode::Char(input_config.key.unwrap())
                        && kind == KeyEventKind::Press
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    println!(
                        "Expected: '{}', Found: '{:?}' {:?}",
                        input_config.key.unwrap(),
                        code,
                        kind
                    );
                }
                _ => {
                    println!("No event");
                }
            }
        }

        // Sleep for a short duration to avoid high CPU usage while waiting for input.
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(20));
    }
}
```

When I run it like this I get the following output when I press space:

```
Expected: 'x', Found: 'Char(' ')' Press
Expected: ' ', Found: 'Char(' ')' Release
Event polled, expecting 'x'
Event polled, expecting ' '
```

So it seems that each thread captures each event and the next thread will not get the same exact event. So in this example, if I want to press space and press to make an action, it will randomly not work because the thread of `x` will steal that event.

How can I "share" the events between threads?

This is how I spawn the threads:

```rust
// The configuration
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct InputConfig {
    pub key: Option<char>,
    // ...

}

let input_configs = vec![
    InputConfig {
        key: Some(' '),
    },
    InputConfig {
        key: Some('x'),
    },
];

// Spawn the threads
let mut handles = vec![];
for (n, config) in input_configs.iter().enumerate() {

    // ...
    let cloned_config = config.clone();
    // ...
    
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        // ...
        wait_until_user_input(&cloned_config)
        // ...
    });

    handles.push(handle);
}

// Wait for all threads to finish
for handle in handles {
    handle.join().expect("Thread panicked");
}
```

Comment: You should only poll for events in a single thread, and then pass messages to the other threads. Or even more likely, you shouldn't be using threads in the first place. It's hard to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve with the threads, since they spend a lot of time sleeping anyway.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'm using this to control the recording/playing of some audio. Using just a thread I could control one track (with space for example), now I want to record/play multiple tracks simultaneously using different buttons, that is why I started using threads.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with audio libraries for Rust, but I assume that your library uses some blocking function calls for audio playback. In that case, the usual approach is to create a thread pool (e.g. `rayon::ThreadPool`) and submit playback tasks from the main thread. The main thread listens for keyboard events, decides what audio to play and tells the thread pool to do the playback. This way, the main thread never blocks on audio and is always ready to listen for new events. You won't need a timeout when polling for events anymore since it's fine for the main thread to block.